# Как с помощью StringFormat в binding xaml заменить символы на символ(*) в строке в контроллере textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Как сделать чтобы в пароле символы поменялись на * с помощью StringFormat??

```
<TextBlock Foreground="White"    Text="{Binding Path=Password}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: а почему бы просто не использовать специальный элемент <PasswordBox/>?

Comment: Мне нужен просто вывод пароля виде * а не ввод пароля, как просто передать текст в PasswordBox не знаю как с помощью  Binding!

Comment: @Vladimir в passwordBox нельзя биндиться. В вашем случае проще завести отдельное get поле, которое будет возвращать нужное количество звёздочек. Ну или я вас не понял

Comment: @alladuh Например:Пароль привет значит должно получиться ******!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в вопросе ты не указал, используешь ты MVVM или нет

1) если не используешь MVVM

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" PasswordChanged="OnPasswordChanged" />
```

.

```
private void OnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var password = passwordBox.Password;
}
```

2) если используешь MVVM

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<PasswordBox PasswordChar="*" x:Name="pwbox" >
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged" >
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasswordChangedCommand }"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=pwbox,  Mode=OneWay}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</PasswordBox>
```

.

```
public ICommand PasswordChangedCommand { get; set; } = new RelayCommand(PasswordChangedCommand);    

private void PasswordChangedCommand(object obj)
{
   yourPassword = ((System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox)obj).Password;
}
```

RelayCommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand 
{        
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: PasswordChanged-происходит при изменении значения свойства Password,мне не чего вводить не надо просто ввести пароль виде ******.

Comment: Ну спасибо за код при изучении MVVM пригодиться)

Comment: @Vladimir дак а что тебе надо? расскажи, что должно быть? ты делаешь авторизацию или что? или ты в какой то элемент хочешь вставить string, и чтобы внутри текст был *? если форму авторизации делаешь, то PasswordBox то, что надо

Comment: @Vladimir вижу, выложил. ты ведь с руки будешь в это поле вводить пароль? в элементе  PasswordBox они будут звездочками

Comment: @ Денис Матюшкин  Я передаю уже готовые данные DataContext = userController.CurrentUser;  для конкретного пользователя  и просто с помощью привязок  вывожу инфу про  юзера! Я ничего вводить не буду тут просто вывод!

Comment: @Vladimir в дальнейшем играет роль этот пароль? или тебе просто надо вывести * в зависимости от длины пароля?

Comment: @ Денис Матюшкин В дальнейшем играет роль этот пароль:нет,надо вывести * в зависимости от длины пароля:да. По логике я уже авторизацию прошел  это просто кабинет пользователя.

Comment: @Vladimir ну если так, то тогда делай вот так

то, что ты получил 
string youPassword = "abcddff";  

пароль со звездочками
youPassword = new String('*', youPassword.Length);

и можно вставить в TextBlock

Comment: @ Денис Матюшкин  Можно как-то  с помощью StringFormat в binding xaml  чтобы  не писать с#  код?

Comment: Пример с датой <TextBlock Foreground="White"    Text="{Binding Path=BirthdayDate, StringFormat=d}"/>

Comment: @Vladimir если не принципиально, то сделай TextBox и у него установи свойство PasswordChar = '*'

Comment: @ Денис Матюшкин  Разве в TextBox есть PasswordChar?

Comment: @Vladimir есть, посмотри в документации на msdn

Comment: @ Денис Матюшкин Как понял TextBox есть PasswordChar в winfoms,а как wpf сделать нз,говорит что нету в данного объекта свойства,спасибо вам за все(